# Compression of table in the Impala

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, impala

I want to compress a table in parquet compression in Impala. Is there any method to compress that table as there are 1000's of files in the HDFS to that particular table.

Answer (score 1):

Parquet is an encoding, not a compression format. Snappy is a compression format commonly used with Parquet

---

It's not clear what your original file types are, but typically simple running an `INSERT OVERWRITE INTO` query will cause the files to get re-collected and "compacted" into a lesser quantity.